# stop UICollectionView from loading while initializing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, lazy-loading

I have a UICollectionView on a separate view let say "dashboardView" for the partial code is giving below,

```
class DashBoardView: UIView
{
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
  override func awakeFromNib() {
        collectionView.dataSource=self
        collectionView.delegate=self
        let nibLineChart = UINib(nibName: "GraphCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.registerNib(nibLineChart, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:lineChartIdentifier )
    }
}
```

Now this view is embeded in a UIViewController and the sample code is giving below,

```
class ViewController : UIViewController
{
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        graphicalDashBoardView = DashBoardView.instanceFromNib() as! DashBoardView
        }

}
```

now what it does as soon the viewdidload call finishes it tries to render the UIcollectionView in the inner view and call the cellForItemAtIndexPath. I just dont want the uicollectionview to load when it finishes viewdidload call. I rather want to load this collectionview on a button click. I know i can reload it by using the collectionview.reloadData() but how i should stop it for the first time loading.
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Can I ask why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve? (Also, I think if you don't add it to the view hierarchy, it won't load the data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this solution.

Don't fill the items when viewdidload delegate method is called.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}
```

On button tap fill the items and collection **view.reloadData()**.

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code from your viewdidload so that it doesn't load at the beginning. Add a button and connect it with a button click event. Inside the click event add your code to load the uicollectionview.

Try this code:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController
{
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()   
     }

}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    graphicalDashBoardView = DashBoardView.instanceFromNib() as! DashBoardView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not saying it's elegant, but you could make a

`var renderCollection: bool = false`

and in your numberOfSectionsInCollectionView and numberOfItemsInSection functions add

`if !renderCollection return 0`

until the moment you want the collection to load when you would do

`renderCollection = true ; collectionView.reloadData();`